# jQuery: Set top position to 1/2 the difference between contained child element and parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, syntax

Ok, so I have some popup bubble effects with absolutely positioned and hidden child elements called `div.caption`.  `div.caption` has a parent element named `a.logo`.

I want to subtract the height of `div.caption` from  `a.logo` and set`.css("top",..)` to be HALF of that number.

For example:

a.logo = 200px (height)
div.caption - 250px (height)

-( (250 - 200)/2 ) = -25

The result should be vertical centering of the child in relation to the parent (despite the fact that it overflows the parent.

I have the following HTML

```
<a class="logo" href="#">
  <div class="caption">Caption Text</div>
</a>

<a class="logo" href="#">
  <div class="caption">Caption Text</div>
</a>

<a class="logo" href="#">
  <div class="caption">Caption Text</div>
</a>
```

and jQuery

```
$("div.caption").each(function() {
    var theHeight = $(this).height();
    var container = $('this').closest('a.logo').height();
    if( theHeight > container ) {
        $(this).css("top",-( (theHeight-container)/2 ) + "px");
    }   
});
```

What's really baffling me is that `$(this).closest('a.logo')` is returning 40px for `height();` but the DOM reports 200px for the elements height.

Somehow my targeting for the variables is off, but I need to use `.this()` since there are multiple instances of all of these targets and I need to set the top property individually.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes around `this`. Your code is currently looking for an element `<this>`, and finding the closest `a.logo`, which does not exist. `height` is set to `null`, which evaluates to zero in a numeric context.

```
var container = $(this).closest('a.logo').height();
```

Comment: I thought "WOW, such a stupid mistake!" but that doesn't fix it unfortunately, still returning the same 40px value which is seemingly incorrect and causing the centering effect to fail.

Comment: Actually, here is a better illustration of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/hvJ8M/3/ ... Absurdly, I can copy this directly into my working code and it doesn't work, even though it DOES work in the JSFiddle demo...

Comment: Are you sure that you're selecting the right elements in your real code? Add `background:red` (or some sort of identifier) in your real code, to see what elements are affected. Also, which browser?

Comment: Yeah, I know that seems like it's the case but I can't find anything different or mis-targeted in my real code ... hmm

Comment: Here's the full HTML copied from the site:

<a class="logo" target="_blank" href="http://wordpress.org"><div class="caption popup" style="top: -129px; "><p>We LOVE WordPress and recommend it as our CMS of choice for projects of all sizes.</p></div><img src="assets/wordpress_logo.jpg" alt="We LOVE WordPress and recommend it as our CMS of choice for projects of all sizes" title="WordPress as a CMS" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-155"></a>

Comment: and I did add `css("background","red")` successfully get red divs

Comment: @Brian Let's discuss further at this channel: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4632/rob-w-and-brian